# Problems using SO with Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, browser-cache

Is anybody else having problems with Firefox in SO today?

For instance:

- can't vote
- toolbar of edit body doesn't show
- close options window doesn't show up.

What's going on? IE seems to work fine.

Comment: What version of FireFox?  I am fine with version 3.0.11, which I believe is current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens sometimes when somehow the jQuery gets messed up and cached this way. Just force a hard refresh of the site or clear your cache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Went through multiple refreshes and even a restart to firefox...

Comment: Hit Ctrl+F5 or Command-Shift-R on a mac to do a hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Firefox 3.0.11 and haven't seen any problems, other than slow loading pages (so some JavaScript stuff isn't available until I manually stop the loading of the page).